# как в астралинуксе подключить библиотеку opengl к проекту?

Tags: qt, opengl, glut, astra-linux

Не получается в астра линуксе поднять проект с openGL-ом .

Вот два примера:
первый это 2dpainting из примера , окна Qt поднимаются а вот сама библиотека опенгл не "подтягивается"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

второй: про файл

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

#-
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/glfw_bin/include/GLFW/ \ # добавляем для удобства чтоб напрямую писать
               $$PWD/glew_bin/include/GL/  \ # только название заголовчного файла без полного пути
               $$PWD/stb_image/

HEADERS += \
    glfw_bin/include/GLFW/glfw3.h \
    glfw_bin/include/GLFW/glfw3native.h \
    glew_bin/include/GL/glew.h \

# --- linux ---

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOpenGL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLEW

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglut

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLU

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
```

майн :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>


#include <glew.h>
#include <freeglut.h>


#define PI 3.14159265358979324

using namespace std;

// Globals.
static float R = 40.0; // Radius of circle.
static float X = 50.0; // X-coordinate of center of circle.
static float Y = 50.0; // Y-coordinate of center of circle.
static int numVertices = 5; // Number of vertices on circle.

// Drawing routine.
void drawScene(void)
{
   float t = 0; // Angle parameter.
   int i;

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

   // Draw a line loop with vertices at equal angles apart on a circle
   // with center at (X, Y) and radius R, The vertices are colored randomly.
   glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
      for(i = 0; i < numVertices; ++i)
      {
         glColor3f((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX, (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX, (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX);
         glVertex3f(X + R * cos(t), Y + R * sin(t), 0.0);
         t += 2 * PI / numVertices;
      }
   glEnd();

//   glFlush();
   glutSwapBuffers();
}

// Initialization routine.
void setup(void)
{
   glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}

// OpenGL window reshape routine.
void resize(int w, int h)
{
   glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0, -1.0, 1.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
}

// Keyboard input processing routine.
void keyInput(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch(key)
   {
      case 27:
         exit(0);
         break;
      case '+':
         numVertices++;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;
      case '-':
         if (numVertices > 3) numVertices--;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;
      default:
         break;
   }
}

// Routine to output interaction instructions to the C++ window.
void printInteraction(void)
{
   cout << "Interaction:" << endl;
   cout << "Press +/- to increase/decrease the number of vertices on the circle." << endl;
}

// Main routine.
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   printInteraction();
   glutInit(&argc, argv);

   glutInitContextVersion(4, 3);
   glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE);

//   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

   glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
   glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow("circle.cpp");
   glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
   glutReshapeFunc(resize);
   glutKeyboardFunc(keyInput);

   glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
   glewInit();

   setup();

   glutMainLoop();
}
```

Сами библиотеки в операциоке присутствуют

а вот результат (этот код прекрасно работает в убунте)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

первую проблему решил :

надо было добавить строку :

```
   QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ForceRasterWidgets, false);
```

вот в коде :

```
#include "window.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ForceRasterWidgets, false);

    QSurfaceFormat fmt;
    fmt.setSamples(4);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(fmt);

    Window window;
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]